# Pass parameter to a function hooked with any action or filter hook

Tags: wordpress

When we create a function to hook with a action or filter hook in Wordpress, we may need some parameter to pass into the function, since we are not manually calling the function. Rather, the action or filter hook will call it when needed.

How we will pas all necessary parameter to the function? Does the action or filter hook provide some parameter when it call any function ? If yes, what is the way to know about all the parameter that any action or filter hook has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read about hook documentation, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference and http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference. These two sites will tell you about the number and type of parameters passed by wordpress when the hook (action or filter) is called.

Or you can look at the wordpress source itself. If you're using an IDE like WebStorm then you can do an **Edit->Find->Find in Path** and search for the hook name to find examples and the source where the hook is called.

For example, to add a logout action, see function `wp_logout()` in `pluggable.php`. The line `do_action('wp_logout');` shows you where the action is called and what parameters are passed (in this case, none).

```
/**
 * Log the current user out.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
function wp_logout() {
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();

    /**
     * Fires after a user is logged-out.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_logout' );
}
endif;
```

Then, to add a custom action to be called at `do_action('wp_logout');`, in your theme's [functions.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained), add this

```
add_action('wp_logout', 'my_on_logout');

function my_on_logout() {
   // do what you want to do
   echo 'hi mom';
}
```

If you see from the `do_action` or `do_filter` or from the documentation the hook has parameters, then you specify them in the fourth argument of your `add_action` or `add_filter`, like so. The `2` below means that there two parameters to be passed to the `publish_product` action: `($post_id, $post)`

```
add_action('publish_product', 'my_on_product_update', 10, 2);
**
 * do something when a product is created
 * @param int $post_id the post id
 * @param WP_Post $post not used
 */
function my_on_product_update($post_id, $post) {
    // do action
    echo 'hi dad';
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Kirby for your answer. I've tried the reference in codex, I really didn't get any idea which parameter they pass to the function rather it shown which parameter they need to work. Your second option can be a way, but i think there is some other way to know about it.

Comment: in your last last block of code, in the function my_on_product_update($post_id, $post) you passed used this two $post_id and $post argument, how you know that, 'publish_product' action hook will pass this two parameter to the function to make it successful.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass arguments via `add_action`. However, you can do this with [do_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action)

From wp documentation:
`<?php do_action( $tag, $arg ); ?>`

`$arg` is the argument that you can pass.

So, you could do something like:

```
add_action( 'your_custom_action', 'your_function' );
```

...

```
do_action( 'your_custom_action', $your_arguments );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you didn't get my question.